# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.GC

Tags: java, exception, runtime-error, tomcat8, classnotfoundexception

I used tomcat server 8.0.

Error: When I run the Tomcat server, I found below error.

SEVERE: Failed to trigger creation of the GC Daemon thread during Tomcat start to prevent possible memory leaks. This is expected on non-Sun JVMs.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.GC
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener.lifecycleEvent(JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener.java:310)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:394)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:580)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:603)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your version of Tomcat is not compatible with the used java version. Check documentation to see which version o java you can use with that particular version of tomcat or upgrade tomcat to the matching java version